# A never-written char "b" appears in a minipage

Tags: beamer, minipage, characters

I'm trying to make a presentation with beamer and I've just started using minipages.

The following code compiles without any issue and the resulting formatting is good, when proper text and graphics are included, although there are probably better ways to do what I'm doing here.

Problem is: a character "b" appears in the slide, at position center-left. 
I've seen that the cause is (should be) the minipage in [cc] position.
If I delete that minipage, the "b" disappears, while if I don't, that letter stays there, no matter what I write in the minipage.

Now I have easily bypassed this issue in my presentation, but I wonder why it happened and how I could have solved it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}    

\begin{minipage}[tl]{0.45\textwidth}
  there's a pic here
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[tc]{0.06\textwidth}
  \center{$\Longrightarrow$} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[tr]{0.45\textwidth}
  pic
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[cl][0.5cm][t]{0.45\textwidth}
  \phantom{skip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[cc][0.5cm][t]{0.06\textwidth}
  \phantom{skip}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[r][0.5cm][t]{\textwidth}
  $\Downarrow$
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[bl]{0.45\textwidth}
  text
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[bc]{0.06\textwidth}
  \phantom{skip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[br]{0.45\textwidth}
  pic
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This code does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bernard the `b` above `text` in the bottom left cell

Comment: Thank you @Bernard, I'm sorry but I don't know why. 
On my computer, it does reproduce it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The optional argument of `minipage` can only be `c` `t` or `b` your extra letters such as `br` are breaking the tests and causing unexpected tokens to be typeset.

The main issue is that (due to memory constraints at the time) latex assumes valid input of one character in `[.]` and tests by doing

```
\if#1b\vbox
\else\if #1t\vtop
\else\ifmmode\vcenter
```

which means that `[b]` makes a `\vbox`, `[t]` makes a `\vtop` and anything else (documented as `c`) makes a `\vcenter`

however if you put in `#1` as two different characters, say `rl` then this is

```
\if rlb\vbox
\else\if rlt\vtop
\else\ifmmode\vcenter
```

so the first two `\if` test `r` against `l` which is false, so you get a `\vcenter` If you put in two equal characters say `[xx]` then you get

```
\if xxb\vbox
\else\if xxt\vtop
\else\ifmmode\vcenter
```

so the first `\if` tests true and you get a `b` typeset ahead of a `\vbox`, as you saw...

Comment: Thank you very much! 
But now I wonder why only that "b" is showed.

Comment: @RM00 The internal test checks if one char is a `b`: if you pass two chars then they are compared and all sorts of oddities ensue! See internal command `\@iiiparbox`

Comment: @RM00 look at answer in a couple of minutes, I'll add some explanation

Comment: This seems a typical instance of the main leaky-abstraction problem with LaTeX: it does not implement enough error-handling on its own, so the user sees error messages (or in this case, behavior!) from the underlying TeX engine instead, which are incomprehensible to the user.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR it is a macro processing language so in part that is inevitable there is no encapsulation of function definitions as you would get in a compiled language,  but the main issue is that when that code was written we were literally down to the last few bytes allowed for token memory. If latex 2e had been any bigger it would not have loaded into emtex at all on a msdos machine of that era. (latex+amsmath left about 50 csnames left for users definitions and cross references,)

Comment: I'm sure it was the best that could be done at the time, and I'm very grateful for LaTeX. But there are possibly not so many constraints now. In most other programming projects, instances like this would at least be treated as technical debt and be on developers' priority to fix when possible. But here, improving the error messages in light of user feedback (or questions that come up like this one: practically a bug report!) does not seem to happen. This is not a complaint; this is just an observation about one of the factors that make the user experience poor for newcomers to LaTeX.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the same reason, the fact that there is no hiding of implementation, and packages can (and do) patch the implementation of any command, so it may rely on the third token of `\@iiiparbox` being `\setlength` _any_ change to the implementation will break some package. Sometimes we do it anyway but it always comes at a cost.

Comment: From what I understand, there are two issues with this code:
(1) The code assumes that if the argument is not `b` or `t` it must be `c`, instead of checking whether it is indeed `c` and if not, throwing an error. Does it have to be this way? (2) The `\if` used is flaky, and cannot really do string comparison. Is it possible to develop a more robust way of comparison and use that instead? (3) Alternatively, could a pre-processor (before it reaches TeX) be included that checks that arguments inside [] to `\minipage` are 1-letter long and warn otherwise?

Comment: ^ My point is, as soon as an error-prone pattern is found, it should be a priority to prevent that error from happening again, so that no other user encounters it. It's not just the case when everything works fine that matters; rather one should care about how to help users not make errors. I don't think the position that others may be depending on our error-prone / buggy code, so we shouldn't improve it, is very conducive to that. (Unless used as reason to fix it right now before more people start to depend on it.) Anyway, this is not a discussion to be held in comments, sorry about that.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR no sorry that is completely wrong. Just because one user in 30 years has reported an issue that `minipage` gives spurious output if given incorrect input does not mean that I should  automatically change the implementation of `minipage` and risk breaking the documents of all current users who may be depending on the existing implementation. I _might_ decide to change it but any such change is a high risk activity.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm absolutely not proposing changing the implementation of minipage. I agree that risk of breaking documents is real and must be rated very highly. I'm not proposing, nor do I know, a solution. All I'm saying is (1) possibility of users making mistakes must also be acknowledged as a risk, and be given _some_ weight at least (2) it is a cultural problem to instead dismiss something as "incorrect input", effectively blaming the user instead of helping them (3) the pattern of writing code without robust error-checking is very common. None of these is specific to minipage BTW. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45723/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-shreevatsar).